# What is R in the following question

Tags: functions

I'm stuck on the following question:

> Show that the function $f(x) = x − \ln(x^2 + 1)$ is increasing in $\mathbf{R}$

Can anyone explain what is the meaning of $\mathbf{R}$ in this context?

Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ - The set of all real numbers perhaps? It is actually the term "growing" that I'd be more puzzled with if I were you. I suppose it means "monotonically increasing", but you'll need to verify that somehow...

Comment: @barakmanos, thanks, the question is a translation from danish, and is directly translated to "growing" but you are probably right. Im still confused about how i am to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Do you know derivatives?

Comment: Calculate the derivative $f'(x)$ and prove that it is positive for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @barakmanos, thanks for your help. Im gonna go for your recent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

With R it is meant the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably referring to $\mathbb{R}$, the set or real numbers, but of course this depends on context. A letter can be used for a reference to any mathematical object, so I would check if there are more details somewhere else in the book/exercise paper.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I dont know. It wasn't me. I'm new here and have no reputation to vote.